# How to click the settings button in a youtube video via a button added with javascript into the browser console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, button, console

What i'm trying to do is theoretically easy, push the button via console:

```
document.querySelector('.ytp-button.ytp-settings-menu').click();
```

It works, but when i try to start it with a button added inside the page, it doesn't work anymore, what am i doing wrong?

```
let personalButton=document.createElement('button');
personalButton.textContent='CLICK ME';
personalButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    document.querySelector('.ytp-button.ytp-settings-menu').click();
});
document.querySelector('#columns #primary #primary-inner #player').appendChild(personalButton);
```

I am not interested in making the code adaptable to all browsers as it is for personal use only, i use firefox.

Thanks in advance for all those who will try to help me

Comment: So are you using an iframe tag for youtube?

Comment: @zhokya No, i enter the code inside the browser console, on the youtube site

Comment: So to be sure: are you just trying to simulate pressing a button on youtube.com from the console?

Comment: Or maybe different: what do you want your code to do and what's wrong with that?

Comment: @zhokya I want to simulate button press on settings button on a youtube video on  youtube.com via a button added with the console, it doesn't open the settings menu. Instead if i just click the button via code inside the console, without the extra button that i add to the page, it works

Comment: are you sure that the click event for your personalButton even fires? You tried something like: personalButton.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    alert('click event works!');
});

Comment: i tried writing some tweaks to your code and it works more or less ... i can post what i have done so far

Comment: The click event is working, but it doesn't open the settings menu, i only get for a moment the blur at the bottom of the video, but without icons, menu...

Comment: when you call your code from the console (not using a button) the movie settings menu shows up?

Comment: @zhokya Yes, it works fine

Comment: Can I get your all code that shows the settings menu form console?

Comment: I want to try it also in my browser if I need to help you...

Comment: Is just this: 
    document.querySelector('.ytp-button.ytp-settings-menu').click();
i missed .click(); on the question

Comment: well, it doesn't work in my browser. I also haven't got firefox, so I think I can't help you... sorry... When i'm using document.querySelector('.ytp-button.ytp-settings-menu').click(); it returns error: Cannot read property 'click' of null, because '.ytp-button.ytp-settings-menu doesn't exist... When i use document.querySelector('.ytp-button,.ytp-settings-menu').click(); it just shows strange black square...

Comment: @zhokya Oh ok don't worry and thanks for trying